# How to optimise linq manipulation to get rows

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

I have list of serial numbers and want to extract the rows from a datatable corresponding to these numbers and against an ID. I am using the below LINQ query for same:

```
//list of serial numbers
var serialNumAlreadyExisted = [1,2,3];
var varID = 2;

//get the corresponding rows for these serial numbers
var duplicateRows = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<int>("ID") == varID && 
    serialNumAlreadyExisted.Any(sr => sr == row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
    select row).ToList();
```

The above code works well for 1-2K rows, but takes a lot of time if there are 50K serial numbers and 50K records in the datatable.

Is there any way to optimize it and reduce the processing time ?

Comment: How about `serialNumAlreadyExisted.Contains(row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER"))` ?

Comment: You could `join` the two, that's probably what I'd do, but I doubt the performance improvement would be all that noticeable on an in-memory set. In fact, I'm quite surprised you're noticing a difference with everything in-memory at all. Am I incorrect to remember that `DataTable`s are eagerly loaded? Is there a lazy version of them these days? I'd definitely believe if loading the data took a while longer, but I'm assuming that's been ruled out?

Comment: try use `DataTable.Select` method. e.g. (hardcoded example to test performance): `DataRow[] dupes = dt.Select(String.Format("Id = 2 AND SERIAL_NUMBER IN ('1','2','3')"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you intended your serial numbers to be a list of `int` or `string`, but taking what you have literally, it probably helps performance to do a one-time conversion to `string`, like so:

```
var serialStringsAlreadyExisted = serialNumAlreadyExisted.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Then you can proceed with a join, which should be more efficient than `Contains` or `Any`:

```
var duplicateRows = (
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<int>("ID") == varID
    join serial in serialStringsAlreadyExisted on row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER") equals serial
    select row)
    .ToList();
```

**Edit**

Just performed a quick speed test. Using `join` completes in about half the time compared your original code for one million rows.

And if you increase the number of items in `serialNumAlreadyExisted` to 20, using `join` takes closer to 20% of the time of the baseline method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest combination of `HashSet` and `Contains` call which gives `O(1)` access. `Any` in this case goes through the collection. In worst case scenario it require 3 comparisons.

```
HashSet<int> serialNumAlreadyExisted = new HashSet<int>();

serialNumAlreadyExisted.Add(1);
serialNumAlreadyExisted.Add(2);
serialNumAlreadyExisted.Add(3);

var duplicateRows = 
    (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<int>("ID") == varID && 
          serialNumAlreadyExisted.Contains(row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
   select row).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the number of rows increase, you find it slow in performance due to a linear search currently being done as it tries to find a number using the following code:

```
serialNumAlreadyExisted.Any(sr => sr == row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
```

Currnt complexity is `O(n^2), to make it O(n)`, is it possible for you to create a Dictionary out of `var serialNumAlreadyExisted = [1,2,3];`

Assuming following is the code, you can make it better, especially the dictionary value

```
var testDictionary = serialNumAlreadyExisted.ToDictionary(x=>x,x=>x);
```

Final code will become as follows:

```
var duplicateRows = 
    (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<int>("ID") == varID && 
          testDictionary.ConatinsKey(row.Field<string>("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
   select row).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are linqing against data-table, which means your records all are in memory. So, if you move your logic to a stored procedure and join the `serialNumAlreadyExisted` with target table, you will have an excellent improvement in performance. But, while you're using `datatabale` tag, seems it's not an option.

Second, `serialNumAlreadyExisted` is an int-array, so how you compare it via `string`?

But, in your short given snippet, there is not much options. Using `Any` or `Contains` or joining in-memory data, makes not much different. Using a `HashSet` for `serialNumAlreadyExisted` can help a little. But, saying again, move the join to a stored procedure, and you will see the difference.